# react-native-file-provider giving error while gradle build

Tags: android, react-native

> > i installed react-native-file-provider and during gradle build i am getting this error. Execution failed for task
> >     ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> >     Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

```
/../test2/android/app/src/main/java/com/testapp2/MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication; 

                           ^

  symbol:   class ReactApplication

  location: package com.facebook.react

/../test2/android/app/src/main/java/com/testapp2/MainApplication.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: package com.facebook.react
/../test2/android/app/src/main/java/com/testapp2/MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
                                                            ^
  symbol: class ReactApplication
/../test2/android/app/src/main/java/com/testapp2/MainApplication.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
/../test2/android/app/src/main/java/com/testapp2/MainApplication.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
         ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
/../`enter code here`test2/android/app/src/main/java/com/testapp2/MainActivity.java:5: error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPackages() in ReactActivity
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
       ^
/../test2/android/app/src/main/java/com/testapp2/MainApplication.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
/../test2/android/app/src/main/java/com/testapp2/MainApplication.java:39: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
8 errors
```